# Mobile keyboard covering input fields

Tags: css, mobile

I'm developing a form for a website on mobile - its my first one, so feeling my way at the moment.

I have the viewport set, and these's nothing special about the CSS - here's how it stands as i'm developing:

```
.input-control {
    padding:3.2rem 0 0.8rem 0;
    position:relative;
}

.input-control input {
    border-bottom:solid 0.1rem @divider;
    color:@secondaryText;
    font-size:1.6rem;
    height:3.2rem;
    line-height:2.4rem;
    padding:0.4rem 0;
    width:100%;
}

.input-control label {
    color:@hint;
    font-size:1.6rem;
    line-height:2.4rem;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:3.6rem;
}
```

The problem is that the keyboard that appears on mobile covers the input field I've focused on if its low down on the page - surely this should be brough into view.

I've been looking round the web, and there's a number of articles about the keyboard, but most refer to apps rather than websites.

Anything I can do about this?

Comment: can you provide html so that we can check,.?

Answer (score 1):

Did you used `position: fixed` on any ancestors ? I had the same problem once and this was the reason, mobile browsers don't always know how to handle it.

Comment: did you find any solution that would fix it?